# "make" command is using wrong clang compiler (to compile CUDA samples) - how to fix this?

Tags: cuda, clang, nvidia, macos-sierra

I am on MacOS Sierra 10.12.4 and trying to make CUDA 8.0 work on my MacBook Pro (Late 2013) with the CUDA compatible NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M.

I followed the [NVIDIA installation guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-mac-os-x/) and installed Xcode 8.2 and the corresponding command line tools, but when I try to compile the samples I get the following error:

> $ make -C 1_Utilities/deviceQuery
>
> /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-8.0/bin/nvcc -ccbin clang++ -I../../common/inc  -m64  -Xcompiler -arch -Xcompiler x86_64  -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_37,code=sm_37 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 -gencode arch=compute_52,code=sm_52 -gencode arch=compute_60,code=sm_60 -gencode arch=compute_60,code=compute_60 -o deviceQuery.o -c deviceQuery.cpp
>   nvcc warning : The 'compute_20', 'sm_20', and 'sm_21' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release (Use -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets to suppress warning).
>   **nvcc fatal   : The version ('30900') of the host compiler ('clang') is not supported**
>   make: *** [deviceQuery.o] Error 1

Here is I think what the problem is:
the "make" command is using the wrong clang, but I don't know how to change/fix this.

Here you can see the two versions of clang, that are on my machine:

> $ clang --version
>
> clang version 3.9.0 (tags/RELEASE_390/final)
>   Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.5.0
>   Thread model: posix
>   InstalledDir: /opt/local/libexec/llvm-3.9/bin
>
> $ /usr/bin/clang --version
>
> Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
>   Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.5.0
>   Thread model: posix
>   InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode_8.2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

How can I make the "make" command use the correct clang version in the folder /usr/bin/clang by default?

Or is there a way to tell the "make" command to use the clang version in the folder /usr/bin/clang explicitly by adding some parameters/tags?

Here is also how my ~/.bash_profile looks like if that helps:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi

# MacPorts Installer addition on 2016-09-26_at_12:06:30: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.

export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

# colorful terminal
export PS1="\[\033[36m\]\u\[\033[m\]@\[\033[32m\]\h:\[\033[33;1m\]\w\[\033[m\]\$ "
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=ExFxBxDxCxegedabagacad
alias ls='ls -GFh'

# CUDA
export PATH=/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-8.0.61/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-8.0.61/lib\
                         ${DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By `make -n` as a dry run, you can see the real command behind `make`. Since I don't have a nvidia based mac, I'll show you the linux version as an example:

```
"/usr/local/cuda-8.0"/bin/nvcc -ccbin g++ -I../../common/inc  -m64    -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_37,code=sm_37 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 -gencode arch=compute_52,code=sm_52 -gencode arch=compute_60,code=sm_60 -gencode arch=compute_60,code=compute_60 -o deviceQuery.o -c deviceQuery.cpp
"/usr/local/cuda-8.0"/bin/nvcc -ccbin g++   -m64      -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_37,code=sm_37 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 -gencode arch=compute_52,code=sm_52 -gencode arch=compute_60,code=sm_60 -gencode arch=compute_60,code=compute_60 -o deviceQuery deviceQuery.o
mkdir -p ../../bin/x86_64/linux/release
cp deviceQuery ../../bin/x86_64/linux/release
```

You can see that `-ccbin` (or `--compiler-bindir`) is the actual argument to set host compiler. Also `nvcc --help` will tell you about this argument.

Then you can either run `nvcc` manually or try to make some changes in the `Makefile`.

If changing the `Makefile`, you can easily find there is a `HOST_COMPILER` variable to set. And the darwin version part is like this:

```
ifeq ($(TARGET_OS),darwin)
    ifeq ($(shell expr `xcodebuild -version | grep -i xcode | awk '{print $$2}' | cut -d'.' -f1` \>= 5),1)
        HOST_COMPILER ?= clang++
    endif
```

I guess you can just change it to your own clang path.

Comment: thanks a lot,
replacing "clang++" with "/usr/bin/clang" in the make files fixed the issue :)